# how to fix dropzone .js, Copying a File in dropzone area

Tags: image, copy, dropzone

[image: 1]

Please look at the gif.

After uploading the image,Drag within the dropzone area to copy image file..

How can I fix this?

```
$("div.dropzone").dropzone({           
      url: "test",
      method: 'POST',
      params : {
        'campaignId' : $('input[name=leadsource]').val(),
        'contactId': $('input[name=EmailAddress]').val(),
        'createDt' : toStringByFormatting(new Date(),'')+'_'+getCurrentDate() 
      },
      autoProcessQueue: false, 
      clickable: true, 
      createImageThumbnails: true, 

      maxFiles: 10, 
      maxFilesize: 100, 
      paramName: function() { return 'image'; }, file)
      parallelUploads: 10, 
      uploadMultiple: true, 
      timeout: 300000,  
      thumbnailHeight: 60,        // Upload icon size
      thumbnailWidth: 60,         // Upload icon size
      addRemoveLinks: true,       
      init: function () {
 
 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed this was removing the ability to have the same file duplicated in the same Dropzone.

**Explanation**:
Every time a new file is added to the dropzone, it will loop through all files currently in queue and compare the new file against the current index. It will check against the name, size and last modified date. If all 3 match, it will remove (not queue) the file the user tried to add.

```
init: function () {
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
        if (this.files.length) {
            var _i, _len;
            for (_i = 0, _len = this.files.length; _i < _len - 1; _i++){
                if(this.files[_i].name === file.name && this.files[_i].size === file.size && this.files[_i].lastModifiedDate.toString() === file.lastModifiedDate.toString()){
                    this.removeFile(file);
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: It is deleted in the queue, but not on the screen. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: So it doesnt exist in the queue but somehow still adding frontend?

Comment: yes.. still adding frontend, Is there any way to fix it..?